# How to start more nodes with eks module in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am trying to provision an eks using Terraform.

I have created the subnets, vpc nat etc...

In my module I use the eks_managed_node_groups to define a public and a private node group. There I define a minimum amount of nodes. However, I only see two nodes when running kubectl get nodes.

I want you to take a closer look at "min_capacity" and "desired_capacity" - the name implies it's the minimum number of nodes present at anytime in the cluster.

My .ft file:

```
...
module "eks" {
  source          = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version         = "18.21.0"
  cluster_name    = local.cluster_name
  cluster_version = "1.20"
  subnet_ids         = ["${element(aws_subnet.public_subnet.*.id, 0)}","${element(aws_subnet.private_subnet.*.id, 0)}"]

  vpc_id = aws_vpc.hubsec-vpc.id

  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    public = {
      subnets          = "${element(aws_subnet.public_subnet.*.id, 0)}"
      desired_capacity = 5
      max_capacity     = 10
      min_capacity     = 3

      instance_type = "t2.small"
      k8s_labels = {
        Environment = "public"
              }
    }
    private = {
      subnets          = "${element(aws_subnet.public_subnet.*.id, 0)}"
      desired_capacity = 5
      max_capacity     = 10
      min_capacity     = 2

      instance_type = "t2.small"
      k8s_labels = {
        Environment = "private"
      }
    }
  }
}
...
```

Min capacity is set to 3 but kubectl get nodes returns:

```
NAME                         STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
ip-10-0-0-133.ec2.internal   Ready    <none>   6m37s   v1.20.11-eks-f17b81
ip-10-0-0-199.ec2.internal   Ready    <none>   6m41s   v1.20.11-eks-f17b81
```

My questions:

a. what does min_capacity and desired_capacity do?
b. how do I go about making sure I have two node groups and 5 nodes (3 public 2 private)

Comment: Are you running the cluster autoscaler or karpenter for node scaling?

Comment: Check on AWS console if 2 managed node groups have been created. Then try to scale the node groups on the console to ensure new node has no problem joining the cluster. If you are open for other option, you can use [eksctl](https://eksctl.io/) to create cluster easily.

Comment: To me it seems you are using the same subnet for both, so probably the latter one has precedence. In other words, `subnets = "${element(aws_subnet.public_subnet.*.id, 0)}"` is used in both `pubilc` and `private` blocks, so you probably want to fetch another element.